# Basic C++ Input Issue

Tags: c++

The following problem gets stuck during the input at (cin << input) and never gets to the if statements.

I ran the code outside of the while loops, and it seemed to work. Can anyone help?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int input = 0;

   bool stop = false;
   while(!stop) {
      while( input == 0 ) {
         cout << "Enter the radix (-1 to exit): ";
         cin >> input;
         if (input == 2) {
            cout << "foo";
         } else {
            cout << "bar";
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Thank you!

EDIT: Fixed! Apparently I forgot to "flush" the cout. So I needed a "cout << endl" after "cin << input".

Comment: You think its getting stuck during input, but try adding `input = 0;` after your inner while loop and you'll see you're just stuck in an infinite loop

Comment: You never set `stop` to `true`.

Comment: There is no `cin << input`.  It will wait at the `cin >> input` for you to type something and press enter. If this doesn't help you then be more descriptive. (The "flush the cout" you mention makes no difference - by default `cin` is tied to `cout`).

Answer (score 1):

Think about your loops. You have

```
while(!stop) 
{
    //do stuff but never change stop
}
```

So it will never exit that loop.